# pycharm cannot see the module "openpyxl" even though i installed

Tags: python, pycharm, ide, openpyxl

I am trying to write a python-script to work with dataframes imported from excel table and another one from another source. In order to read excel file into a pandas dataframe i selected "`openpyxl`" as a preferred engine, however PyCharm claims there is no such module - even though I have earlier installed it.

I am working on conda and i tried to install it both using pycharm terminal and my macbook terminal: when i retype "conda install openpyxl" it returns me

```
"# All requested packages already installed."
```

So please help me because it confuses me that PyCharm keeps screaming

```
"ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'openpyxl'.  Use pip or conda to install openpyxl."
```

while terminal says i already have that module installed

Comment: Check that PyCharm is using the same virtual environment as your prompt. Usually we prefer environments (virtual environments, or conda environments), each for every project. PyCharm tell you if you want a new env. And probably you accepted. So, go on the right env, or install in PyCharm (which includes a graphical interface to conda and pip)

Comment: I did install it in pycharm terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may happen because your pycharm is using a different interpreter than your command line.

To solve it:

In Pycharm, go to File, settings, project Interpreter, in the right top corner click the + button. Search for openpyxl and click Install package to install the latest version of the package.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I don't have just "Settings" in File in pycharm, i have either "Manage IDE settings" or "New Project settings".

Comment: Should be the IDE settings

Comment: It is "Preferences" on mac, and not on "File" but on "PyCharm". It is a standard way to put menus in a consistent way across all mac apps.

Comment: Thank you for help guys, it really helped, i figured there was second interpreter i was using for my script, so i just added the necessary module for that interpreter and it started working.